# Visual Studio error C2061: syntax error: identifier

Tags: c++, syntax-error, identifier

```
//Species.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Species
{
protected:
    int HP, GroundAttack, AirAttack, MoveMode;
public:
};

// Protoss.h
#pragma once
#include "Species.h"
#include "Terran.h"

class Protoss : public Species
{
protected:
    int PS;
public:
    virtual void Input();
    virtual void Output();
    void B_AbilityAttack_A(Terran *);
};

// Terran.h
#pragma once
#include "Species"
#include "Protoss.h"

class Terran : public Species
{
public:
    virtual void Input();
    virtual void Output();
    void A_AbilityAttack_B(Protoss *);
};
```

> "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Terran'"
>
> "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Protoss'"
>
> error in: void A_AbilityAttack_B(Protoss *) and void B_AbilityAttack_A(Terran *)

How to fix it?

After fix In a method of class Protoss, I wrote:

```
void Protoss::B_AbilityAttack_A(Terran *x)
{
    if (this->AbilityAttack() == 0 && x->GetMoveMode() == 0)
    {
        x->SetHP(x->GetHP() - this->GAttack());
    }
    else if (this->AbilityAttack() == 1 && x->GetMoveMode() == 0)
    {
        x->SetHP(x->GetHP() - this->GAttack());
    }
    else
    {
        x->SetHP(x->GetHP() - this->AAttack());
    }
}
```

> And error in x : "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed"

So how to fix it?

Comment: You can remove `#include "Protoss.h"` from Terran.h and instead write `class Protoss;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. Remove the include of `Protoss` by `Terran` and vice versa, the use forward declarations instead.

```
// Protoss.h
#pragma once
#include "Species.h"

class Terran;
class Protoss : public Species
{
protected:
    int PS;
public:
    virtual void Input();
    virtual void Output();
    void B_AbilityAttack_A(Terran *);
};

// Terran.h
#pragma once
#include "Species"

class Protoss;
class Terran : public Species
{
public:
    virtual void Input();
    virtual void Output();
    void A_AbilityAttack_B(Protoss *);
};
```

This will work because you don't need the full class definitions because the arguments are pointers, you just need to forward declare them.

Comment: Don't forget the re-add the includes in the cpp files though

Comment: Also a pointer `Species*` can be used instead of `Terran*` and `Protoss*`, because these classes are derived from the `Species` class. In this case there is no need to use forward declaration.

Comment: @DânNguyễn All formatting gets lost in the comment section. If you'd like to elaborate your question and include this code, please edit your original question.

Comment: @DânNguyễn When you remove the `#include` from the `.h` file to use a forward declaration, you have to add the `#include` to the `.cpp` file so you get the full class definition when you try to use that type.